# Phpmyadmin open .log file

Tags: mysql, logging

How can I open a MySQL.log file in path `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log`?
I use phpmyadmin. My "general_log" is on. I try open this file with PUTTY and i don't know what command to enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my Debian system, the MySQL General Log is stored in `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log`. What do you hope to do with this file?

To view it through PuTTY, you'd use your favorite text editor, pager, or logfile parsing tool or search utility. I use `less` because this is a better task for a pager than a text editor and prefer it to `more`.

```
less /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

Since it's a text file, phpMyAdmin wouldn't know what to do with it, so there's no point to loading it through phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur respond.
In mysql.log file i don't see logs (ip, username, date, time etc.) from all queries so where i can find them?

Comment: You have to explicitly turn on logging (which you can do in my.cnf or at runtime); most distributions disable it by default. You might also wish to double check in your configuration file (possibly `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) for the path specified by `general_log_file`.

Comment: I'd like write a script, which is saving logs (ip, date, time etc.) to file on my server. Do you have some ideas? I can't edit any file on mysql because i don't have some privilege.

Comment: You can still turn on logging at runtime (if you have proper MySQL permissions!), but that means the log will stop whenever your MySQL service restarts (until you manually enable logging again), so it's not an ideal solution. Unfortunately, to do this properly it requires modifying the configuration file; you can either live with the workaround of needing to manually enable it at run-time or ask the administrator to enable it.